# jQuery customized select list

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, customization

Where can i find a jquery customized select list, that works even on IE?

Comment: I think he means a stylised select list (eg with CSS) - not all controls (especially select lists) style well across all browsers. The only way to create a cross-browser stylised select list is to "hand-roll" your own, using DIVs, click events and so on. He's looking for a jQuery plugin that does this so he doesn't need to hand-roll his own - jquery.ui.selectable will do this for him (as per my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Check out "selectable" in jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

I think this is what you are after.

Because this is not a standard form-field/form-element, you will need to add some code to create hidden inputs (or CSS-hidden select lists) to update and send the form-data back with your form submission, but this would not be difficult